# Expected <eof> from ffi.cast in LuaJIT

Tags: c, sqlite, lua, luajit

I am trying to write a LuaJIT FFI module for sqlite3. The exec function takes a callback for each row returned. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html

in LuaJIT I simply enter

```
ffi = require 'ffi'
ffi.cast("int (callback*)(void*,int,char**,char**)")
```

which I think should be the correct cast for a function pointer as per the SQLite docs, but I get:

```
stdin:1: '<eof>' expected near 'callback'
```

I am sure I have something wrong in the syntax here, but I can't find any documentation/examples for FFI.cast() used for a function pointer with args.

Comment: `your_function = require 'ffi'.cast("__stdcall int (*)(void*,int,char**,char**)", your_pointer_to_function)`

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks Egor. If you made it an answer, I could accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm too lazy :-)

Comment: Are you aware that there is an [existing LuaJIT FFI binding](https://github.com/ColonelThirtyTwo/lsqlite3-ffi) to sqlite3?

Comment: yup, there are 3. I am making a binding for luvit, and using lsqlite3-ffi as a reference. This line of code is actually from lsqlite3-ffi. thanks